# How do you add more than one command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do you add more than one command/function to python.py ?
This is my code:

```
import os
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"{client.user} is online")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith("https://"):
    await message.delete()
  
client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: I like how he said THIS IS PYTHON and it starts of with an  indentation error

Comment: I suggest you to read https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html.

Comment: You can't use commands with `discord.Client`. You have to use `.ext.commands.Bot` which is a subclass of `Client` anyway plus commands support. [Read here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html)

Answer (score 1):

To add more commands,
Here is the syntax for a new command

```py
@client.command(name="wave")
async def command_name(ctx,user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author} has waved to {user.mention}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord    
from discord.ext import commands
```

Having at least these two imports is a must. Now you should be prepared to create more commands,
as a template

```
@client.command()
async def command_name(arguments) : 
   #rest of your code here
```

and if the command is inside a cog

```
@commands.command()
async def command_name(self, other arguments) : 
   #rest of your code here
```

I suggest you to read the docs though, blindly follow won't help